# RHEL 6.4 - Clean Install - SSD - Does not see hard drive

Tags: partitioning, ssd, redhat-enterprise-linux

**Apologies if I am missing any pertinent information, this is the first time asking advice on a forum.**

**Requirements:**

Software:

RHEL 6.4
AND
RHEL 5.3 - NOT simultaneously, just have multiple computers to install to that have different requirements with the exact matching hardware.

Hardware:

120GB SSD

EMB-H81B

Issue: When booting to RHEL (6.4,5.3) disc, during initial set up, I am receiving an error.

RHEL 6.4: 

**Error Partitioning
Could not allocate requested partitions: not enough free space on disks. Press 'OK' to exit the installer.**

RHEL 5.3

**Specified nonexistent disk sda in clearpart command**

My thoughts are that it is not recognizing the SSD in either OS. 
I have replaced the SSD with a standard HDD and was able to install 6.4, still no 5.3. - This was to ensure that it was the SSD causing the issue and not the motherboard.

**Also, please be sensitive to the fact that I am extremely new to Linux so please explain high level answers in such a way that would be understandable to someone trying to learn. And please take into consideration that I cannot change out ANY hardware or OS versions.**

Comment: I wonder if the SSD's have come pre-partitioned or something.  I would try booting with a Pendrive, then seeing if the disks are accessible through that.  Specifically I'd run fdisk /dev/sdX if the disks are found and delete all partitions on the disk - then try a re-install.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I went down that road too a little.. I removed all partitions from the SSD using Windows Disk Management. Still getting the same errors.
To further expand, I also converted the MBR to GPT and tried pre-partitioning. 
- Between each step I tried to install RHEL with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I bypassed the kickstart file for RHEL6 and it installed the OS on the SSD. 

What was throwing me in the kickstart was - 

**bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=sda --append=" rhgb crashkernel=auto quiet"** 
and line
 **clearpart --all --drives=sda**

It sounded as if it was specifying a specific disc location vs being open to any drive available. As I said, I am extremely new to Linux. If my thought process is wrong, please correct me and help me learn. 
Thanks!